# Python - Add seconds to time object

Tags: python, time, seconds

I have a time object which looks like this:

```
time.struct_time(tm_year=2012, tm_mon=8, tm_mday=11, tm_hour=18, tm_min=48, tm_sec=23, tm_wday=5, tm_yday=224, tm_isdst=0)
```

I was wondering if there was an easy way add seconds to it.

I want to add 4497 seconds to it.

I've previously tried to convert each individual component to seconds and add them.

Thanks,

Parth

Comment: Seconds since when? January 1, 1970?

Comment: Note that if you can use the [`datetime` module](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) instead, this is as simple as `old_datetime + datetime.timedelta(seconds=4497)`.

Comment: If you mark that as an answer i'll upvote it and accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** This answer applies to an old version of the question asking how to convert a `time.struct_time` into an `int` representing seconds and does not answer what the question currently asks (how to add a number of seconds to a `time.struct_time`).

---

Assuming you want to convert to seconds **since January 1, 1970**, you can use:

- [`time.mktime`](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.mktime) for local time.
- [`calendar.timegm`](http://docs.python.org/library/calendar.html#calendar.timegm) for UTC time.

These conversions (and their inverses) are detailed in [the documentation for the `time` module](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html).